# Why my script doesn't want to debug?

Tags: php, debugging

I'm trying to debug (with var_dump) the script that i'm creating but nothing is displayed in the page (i mean white page). I may did some mistake with the quote or something but i don't know id it's the reason .

What did i do wrong ?

```
<?php  
include('config.php'); 

// Si l'utilisateur n'est pas connecté il ne peux pas accédé à la page reservé au prenium
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
    echo 'Désolé vous devez être connecté pour accédé à cette page.';
}
else {
    $duration = $_POST['duration'];
    $uid = $_SESSSION['user_id'];
    if (array_key_exists($duration, $suscribe['prices']))
    {
        $custom = "action=suscribe&uid=$uid&duration=$duration";
        $request = array(
            'METHOD'=>'BMCreateButton',
            'VERSION'=>'87',
            'USER'    => $paypal['USER'],
            'PWD'=> $paypal['PWD'],
            'SIGNATURE'=> $paypal['SIGNATURE'],
            'BUTTONCODE'=>'HOSTED',
            'BUTTONTYPE'=>'BUYNOW',
            'BUTTONSUBTYPE'=>'SERVICES',
            'L_BUTTONVARD0'=>'business'.$paypal['mail'],
            'L_BUTTONVARD1'=>"item_name=Compte prenium $duration mois",
            'L_BUTTONVARD2'=>"amount=".$prices['duration'],
            'L_BUTTONVARD3'=>"curency_code=EUR",
            'L_BUTTONVARD4'=>"no_note=1",
            'L_BUTTONVARD5'=>"",
            'L_BUTTONVARD6'=>"",
            'L_BUTTONVARD7'=>"",
            'L_BUTTONVARD8'=>"custon=$custom",
            );

        $request = http_build_query($request);
        var_dump($request); die();

        )
}
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
// Constantes pour l'abonnement
$suscribe = array(
    'prices' => array(
        1=>10,
        3=>25,
        6=>50,
        )
    );

// Constantes pour paypal
$paypal = array(
        'mail'=>'test@project-heberg.fr',
        'USER'=>'test_api1.project-heberg.fr',
        'PWD'=>'U22EK73YXA3SR8MT',
        'SIGNATURE'=>'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Aolcj.om6WciFJa0Q6jdnOZEQziM',
        'sandbox'=>'sandbox.',
    );
?>
```

Comment: A white page usually means that there is an error. Check your logs.

Comment: Does your code actually pass in that `if` where you put the `var_dump` ? I think not... Oh and by the way, you should write "pour accéder à cette page" , with "er" at the end of "accéder" ;-)

Comment: Yes i should write "er" ^^ I can't see any error in my console .

Comment: Look guys, just choose here, http://www.project-heberg.fr/CREAZ/autozoom/abonnement/suscribe.php then you will have a white page, not a debug or something.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry if this must be a comment but I cant yet)

My guess is that you need to remove the last comma in each declaration of array.

```
$request = array(
        'METHOD'=>'BMCreateButton',
        'VERSION'=>'87',
        'USER'    => $paypal['USER'],
        'PWD'=> $paypal['PWD'],
        'SIGNATURE'=> $paypal['SIGNATURE'],
        'BUTTONCODE'=>'HOSTED',
        'BUTTONTYPE'=>'BUYNOW',
        'BUTTONSUBTYPE'=>'SERVICES',
        'L_BUTTONVARD0'=>'business'.$paypal['mail'],
        'L_BUTTONVARD1'=>"item_name=Compte prenium $duration mois",
        'L_BUTTONVARD2'=>"amount=".$prices['duration'],
        'L_BUTTONVARD3'=>"curency_code=EUR",
        'L_BUTTONVARD4'=>"no_note=1",
        'L_BUTTONVARD5'=>"",
        'L_BUTTONVARD6'=>"",
        'L_BUTTONVARD7'=>"",
        'L_BUTTONVARD8'=>"custon=$custom"
        );

$suscribe = array(
'prices' => array(
    1=>10,
    3=>25,
    6=>50
    )
);

// Constantes pour paypal
$paypal = array(
    'mail'=>'test@project-heberg.fr',
    'USER'=>'test_api1.project-heberg.fr',
    'PWD'=>'U22EK73YXA3SR8MT',
    'SIGNATURE'=>'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Aolcj.om6WciFJa0Q6jdnOZEQziM',
    'sandbox'=>'sandbox.'
);
```

Have you try like that?

Comment: Yes i tried but in an array you have to write at the end of the last line a comma ^^  It doesn't change anything .

Comment: @raziel, PHP allows a comma after the last element in an array - it's not a syntax error.  This makes each line more consistent, so it's just a little bit easier when you're adding more elements to the array later.

Comment: Sorry just was a guess, but what about the semicolons? Php also allows sentences without semicolons at the end?

Comment: What is doing a parenthesis after "die();" @Brian?